# How Can I access text with font face of "courier new" using CSS only?

Tags: css

I am writing a css code to disable text selection. Included some css as this.

```
 -webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
```

However I want text with a font "Courier New" to be able to get selected. As the text with this font face will be a code, or a command.

This looks a bit tricky, or not at all possible? ;)

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to my mind, that could work out, is to create a CSS-class that has to be attached to all elements which should use the specific font. I know it's not really what you want, but any other real solution would use Javascript in some form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where you can allow selection within a `code` element, or something with the class `.code`. I imagine you can adapt one of these to allow you to target the element that is currently displaying your code.

Also included some example JQuery code that checks all elements' `font-family`, this isn't the most efficient way of doing this... would recommend using the class / tag option.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

> Note @DigitalJedi mentioned the default is `user-select: auto`

---

## Demo

```js
// Cycle through all elements
$("*").each(function() {

  // Check if element has the font "courier-new" set
  // Using indexOf
  if ($(this).css('font-family').toLowerCase().indexOf("courier new") >= 0 ) {

    // Add the code class if it is
    $(this).addClass("code");

  }
  
  // Check if element has the font "courier-new" set
  // Using Regular Expression
  // i - ignore case
  if (/courier new/i.test( $(this).css('font-family') )) {
  
    // Add the code class if it is
    $(this).addClass("red-text");
  
  }
  
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

code, .code {
  font-family: courier new;
  -webkit-touch-callout: all;
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
  user-select: all;
}

.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some text here</p>
<code>Some code here (code element)</code>
<p>Some more text</p>
<p class="code">Some code here (paragraph element with code class)</p>
<p>Some more text</p>
<p style="font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;;">Some code here (paragraph with font set to courier new, selectable via JQuery)</p>
<p>Some more text</p>
```

Comment: I think the default value for `user-select` is `auto` isn't it?

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you @OliverTrampleasure
It will obviously need one more request to fetch jQuery. But this serves purpose. I did not have access to inline code.

Comment: Can we add regex here, as my code is dynamic and may include backup font as this.
<span style="font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;">java -versions</span>

How shall we shape the code? using regex? or contains?
I am thinking here from the optimization point of view, as HTML page may have 10,000 of words.

Or any other smart way you can suggest?

Comment: Not sure about performance, but I've added two different methods above. It might be worth experimenting with your webpage, asking the code to print to the console at the start and end of the process. If you switch the selection method you will be able to tell which is faster. I'd be interested in hearing the results. I would imagine regex is likely faster

Comment: marked this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Despite other answers, it can be done with CSS, although you might not be pleased with an inline style attribute in your html tags.

The attached code shows that you can use a CSS attribute selector `[some-attrib]` and search for a specific string in, for example, an inline `style` attribute.

**UPDATE** Caution!

Inline styling has precedence over CSS classes, so this solution should not work (using class `.test` to modify the inline `style` attribute). However, Firefox, Chrome and Edge accept this (because `font` is a 'shorthand property'??), IE11 does not. (I checked all four browsers).

Disturbing and puzzling...

**UPDATE 2**
Figured out the previous update => the value of inline definitions themselves cannot be changed, only other, undefined (or in CSS declared rules) with equal or lower precedence.

```css
.test {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
.test[style*="Courier New"] {
-webkit-touch-callout: text;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: text;
 user-select: text;
}

.font {
font-size: 2rem /* works */
}
.test[style*="16px/30px"] {
font-size: 20px;    /* won't work */
line-height: 35px;  /* ditto */
}
.test[style*="blue"] {
color: green;       /* won't work */
}
.test[style*="font-family: 'Courier New'"] {
color: green;       /* works great */
font-size: 20px;    /* ditto */
line-height: 35px;  /* also  */
}
```

```html
<p class="test">default unselectable font</p>

<p class="test" style="font: italic bold 16px/30px 'Courier New',Georgia, serif">selectable Courier New</p>

<p class="test" style="font: 16px/30px serif; color: blue">blue serif font sized 16px/30px</p>
<p class="test" style="font-family: 'Courier New'">green selectable Courier New</p>

<p class="test font" style="font-family: 'Courier New'">font test 1 Courier New</p>
<p class="font" style="font-family: 'Courier New'">font test 2 Courier New</p>
```

Comment: Great approach, But I do not have access to inline code and can not add classes.
I am already doing this for text boxes and text areas. Thanks for your time.

Can not we do some hack to just access element with font face "FONT_XYZ"?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot really be done in CSS, since there is no selector for different fonts.

**HOWEVER** you could achieve the same thing using different classes, for different types of text:

```css
.text{
 -webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
}


.code{
 -webkit-touch-callout:auto;
-webkit-user-select:auto;
-moz-user-select:auto;
-ms-user-select:auto;
 user-select:auto;
font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
user-select:normal;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">this is some </span><span class="code">code</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `p` tag non-selectable and wrap Courier New text in code elements which is a standard tag for code. Like

```css
p {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text here</p>
<code>function xyc(arguments) {
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; return test;
<br>
}</code>
<p>Some more text</p>
<p>Some more text</p>
```